# Using formattable in R with dynamic column headers

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, formattable

Formattable allows one make formatted data output in R and Rshiny.  A good explanation is here:  https://www.r-bloggers.com/formatting-table-output-in-r/

[image: example code]

In the "formatter" function above you can see that the column headers are referenced.  I would like to know if this code can be written in a way as to work with dynamic column headers that change based on a users input to an rshiny app.
I was thinking that there may be a way to reference the column number instead of the specific name but I have been unsuccessful at doing this thus far.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I find the word "dynamic" to be meaningless in most instances of its use on SO. Post a data example (or code with user input that you specify) and say what is expected. I cannot quite believe "dynamic" has its own tag. And the description on the tag makes me think it doesn't fit, since R is an interpreted language. Posting a picture for code is severely deprecated on SO.

Comment: As a simplified example from above, say that this code was from within an rShiny app that had a selectInput that allowed the user to select a date and then displayed the stock price for that date.  Furthermore, the header of the 3rd column would change to be paste0("Value ",input$date).  With the column header changing I am unsure of how to reference this column in the formattable function above where "Value = color_tile("white","orange")".  I was thinking of referring to the column by position instead of name with something such as "DF[3] = " but no success yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the function is looking for a named list to match up to the names in the data.frame. I recommend that you create the list with your desired formats, then set the name(s) of the format arguments "dynamically" to match what you are displaying.

e.g.:

```
myFormats <- list( formatter("span") )
names(myFormats) <- input$userEnteredChoiceHere

formattable(DF, myFormats)
```

Without actually reproducible code though, it is hard to help you more than that. A picture of code is not easy to work from.